# c# windows 8 hide keyboard when a combobox is present

Tags: c#, combobox, keyboard, hide, windows-8.1

I want to hide the virtual keyboard from a windows 8 application. I know that if a set the focus at a button it will hide, but my problem is that if i do that then the combobox that is under the textbox is frozen and cann't be opened. My code:

```
<Grid Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>  

<TextBox Margin="12,12,12,12"  Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Name="aksiografo_textbox"
                     Text="{Binding ChequeNumber, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<ComboBox
Name="BankListPicker"
Grid.Row="1"
Margin="12,12,12,12" 
SelectedItem="{Binding Bank, Mode=TwoWay}"                        
ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LiPickerTemplate}" />
</Grid

private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    ok_button.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Pointer);
}
```

Comment: That's because the ComboBox.Tapped event bubbles and *also* fires the Grid.Tapped event.  Creating a Tapped event handler for the ComboBox and setting e.Handled = true fixes that problem, but not the keyboard popup.  You can't solve it this way, I don't think there's any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The problem indeed is the tapped event. I created a boolean combotapped=false;

```
private void combo_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    combotapped = true;
}

private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (combotapped == false)
   ok_button.Focus(Windows.UI.Xaml.FocusState.Pointer);

   combotapped = false;
}
```